# how can i inform iphone app whenever new value is posted from rails server?

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails app serving iphone app. Consider if a user posts a value it is saved in the server and i wanted to notify the rest of users that new value is posted. I wanted to do this because the user has to frequently send request to check if any new value is posted and this would cause more requests. So instead i want the server itself to notify whenever new value is pushed.

How can i do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you can use [push notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) to accomplish this with iOS clients.

Note that there are a number of caveats with this approach, however (users can opt out of receiving push notifications, delivery of push notifications is not guaranteed even when the user has opted in, etc.), so it is not an appropriate solution if you need 100% reliability.

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications are fine but cannot guarantee you a 100% reliability like aroth mentioned. You can try using XMPP and you can easily find an XMPP client for iOS as well as server side code required in Ruby/PHP. Check the following link...

[XMPP Clients](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/)